# is there a way to get the colour theme from the R GUI into Emacs?

Tags: emacs, r, ess

I find it hard to sort through all the messages in the *R* frame(?) in emacs, and I was wondering if it'll be easy to change the colours so that it looks more like the R GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, I use

```
(set-background-color "gray10")
(set-foreground-color "wheat")
(set-cursor-color "wheat")
(set-mouse-color "wheat")
(set-face-background 'default "black")
(set-frame-font "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono-10")   ;; you may not have that font
```

in `~/.emacs` (or rather a file source from it). These colors work well for numerous programming languages, and in particularly R, C/C++, SQL, shell scripts, ...   You can probably adapt these at will to suit your preference (here the R GUI).

See the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org) for countless alternatives.

Comment: thanks 

and is there any way of getting everything after "Error" to be the same colour, like it is in R GUI?
Right now, the "Error in" bit is in pale blue and the message after that is in the normal text colour (white).